# Python - selección de valores de un dataframe comparando con una lista

Tags: python

Tengo los datos siguientes:
Dataframe

```
print(approval_polls.head(5))

 start_date    end_date         pollster    sponsor  sample_size population  \
0  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist       1500.0          a   
1  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist        376.0          a   
2  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist        523.0          a   
3  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist        599.0          a   
4  2020-02-07  2020-02-09  Morning Consult        NaN       2200.0          a
```

Lista

```
print(excel_prep)
['Monmouth University', 'Selzer & Co.', 'ABC News/The Washington Post', 'YouGov',...]
```

Para hacer la comparación de la columna `pollster` con la lista y en caso de coincidir, quedarme con la fila entera del dataframe `approval_polls`, hago:

```
approval_polls = approval_polls[approval_polls['pollster'].isin(excel_prep)]
```

El resultado es

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [start_date, end_date, pollster, sponsor, sample_size, population, party, subject, tracking, text, approve, disapprove, url]
Index: []

Process finished with exit code 0
```

El resultado debería ser:

```
 start_date    end_date         pollster    sponsor  sample_size population  \
0  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist       1500.0          a   
1  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist        376.0          a   
2  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist        523.0          a   
3  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist        599.0          a
```

Alguien me sabría decir por qué no compara bien los valores la función `isin()`?

Muchas gracias

Comment: No sé qué estás haciendo mal. A mi con tus datos me sale el resultado que esperas. Creo que la única forma de ayudarte es que subas la excel (el archivo .xlsx o .csv) a un almacén como Dropbox o Drive, y edites la pregunta para poner un enlace a ese fichero, de modo que podamos probar exactamente con tus datos y no con la versión texto que pegas en el enunciado. También convendría que pusieras la línea de código con la que lees esa excel.

Comment: @abulafia, creo que ya he localizado el problema, pero igualmente tengo que consultarlo porque no entiendo por qué falla. Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @icatalan A mi también me sale el resultado correcto